# store an EditText value into SQLite database line by line

Tags: android, sqlite, android-edittext, android-sqlite

i made an EditText that displayed value with multiple line like this...

[image]

i want to keep that value in a SQLite database. this is the code i use:

```
export.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final View export_layout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.export_layout, null);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    MainActivity.this);
            builder.setView(export_layout);
            builder.setTitle("Input new DB");
            builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int which) {
                    editText1 = (EditText) export_layout.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    String table = editText1.getText().toString();
                    String val = textStatus.getText().toString();
                    db.execSQL("create table "+table+"(ANY text)");
                    db.execSQL("insert into "+table+" values('"+val+"')");
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("back",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });
```

TextStatus is an EditText where the value is displayed like the image above. editText1 is where the user input the table name.

the problem is when i save the value, the whole value is inserted into one cell. i want the value to be separated per line then inserted into a single cell for each line.

is there any way to do that?

edit:
this is how i set the text in TextStatus:

```
x = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) 
        {
            results = wifi.getScanResults();
            size = results.size();
            if (size > 0) {
                for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
                    ScanResult scanresult = wifi.getScanResults().get(i);
                    String ssid = scanresult.SSID;
                    int rssi = scanresult.level;
                    String bssid = scanresult.BSSID;
                    String rssiString = String.valueOf(rssi);
                    textStatus.append(ssid + "," + bssid + "," + rssiString + "\n");
                }
                unregisterReceiver(x); //stops the continuous scan
                textStatus.append("------------"+j+"\n");
                j++;
            } 
        }
    };
```

Comment: can you show us how you set text in to edittext. then its easy..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Scanner:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(val);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    //Insert the line here
}
```

Update: This is how it should looks like in your codes

```
editText1 = (EditText) export_layout.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
String table = editText1.getText().toString();
String val = textStatus.getText().toString();
db.execSQL("create table "+table+"(ANY text)");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(val);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    db.execSQL("insert into "+table+" values('"+line+"')");
}
```

Comment: Just a side note, scanner is however claimed to have slow responsiveness, thus you may want to pop some loading if your val is very long.

Comment: thanks for your answer but it gave me force close notifiction. and when i check it only has the first line of the value stored. any other solution?

Comment: oops sorry, i forgot something, i put `db.execSQL("create table "+table+"(ANY text)");` inside the loop while it should be outside the loop ... everything works fine now, thanks dude! i'll vote this answer as accepted :)